# use 'gradle init' to migrate maven to gradle, but it's ignoring dependencies declared in pom project of parents projects

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-plugin

I have a multi project which is construct by maven: https://github.com/tiancai110a/parent-project:

its struct is like this:

```
parent. 
   | 
   |--core
   |  |
   |  |
   |------service
   |  |
   |-------webapp
```

`core`, `service`, `webapp` is jar package.
`parent` is a pom package.
dependency relationship  is like the pic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD4Cl.png

all the `junit` is come from `parent`.
`service`  and `webapp` also dependent on the `core`

then I run `gradle init` to generate `build.gradle` from pom.xml in the root of the project.

then I suppose to have depenency of `junit` somewhere in the in the `build.gradle` like:

```
dependencies {testImplementation 'junit:junit-dep:4.11'}
```

which if I do the same operation in a single project it will translate from pom.xml configuration:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

but it din't, it just ignore the `junit` depenency which is defined in the `parent/pom.xml`,
and then of course I am fail to build because I don't declare the unit dependency,
why, How can I get this depenency transformed into `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Gradle official documentation on how to do this? [Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html)

I have checked your repo and it looks like what Gradle init did was a mess: it created an app folder for you for every module that you have, which is what it does when you select "application" from the Gradle init menu... That does not look like it detected the Maven project correctly.

My suggestion is to init an empty new project and then move your code in manually as modules or to delete everything added with your previous Gradle init, check the documentation and try again to migrate.